# Prestashop : Error While updating product

Tags: prestashop, product

I'm using Prestashop version 1.5.5.0. When I try to update a product it gives me three types error sometimes internal server error, sometimes 504 gateway time out and sometimes blank page. When I activate developer mode I see nothing. In the error log of my server host I didn't find any error but sometimes it give "Premature end of script headers: php-stable". 
I'm getting temporary solution of this problem by clearing smarty cache in the backoffice.
I was running my website on fastcgi but for this problem I stopped using that. Can anyone shed some light on this ? My website is fast but the script is taking a lot of time to execute. Here is the website "http://www.allworldfurniture.com"

Answer (score 1):

It seems you are using a host having less capacity. It is always better to use ur VPS or dedicated server if you are using more than 300-500 products.

Comment: I think That will work and yes I'm planning to upgrade my host.